# AJAX - Pass two arrays from javascript to python function

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I'm trying to pass two arrays of numbers, contact and remove, which correspond to various checkboxes on the client side, to a Python function in my Flask app. I am using an AJAX call and this is what I've crafted so far but with no luck, I keep getting a 400 error response.

I am using json.loads(request.args.get(name_of_array) to attempt to retrieve the data in Python.

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/email_task', methods=['POST'])
def email_task():
  #get the number of e-mails that we are sending
  contact_comps = json.loads(request.args.get('contact'))
  remove_comps = json.loads(request.args.get('remove'))
```

**index.html**

```
$('#danish-form').submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var contact = [45,200,100,1234,94,123,3490,1234,345,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
        var remove = [3,4,5,];
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/email_task',
            data: { contact: contact, remove: remove},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, status, request) {
                status_url = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
                update_progress(status_url, '#progress div');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Unexpected error');
            }
        });
    });
```

**Console error message**

```
POST http://localhost:5001/email_task 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

Note, this is not the full Flask app but just a small subset of it, I'm making a small sub app to try to learn how to integrate the Celery Task Queue into my project.

**Update**

This is the updated ajax call and what I am able to access in Python, now just trying to figure out what module/function to use to extrapolate this

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/email_task',
            data: { 
                contact: JSON.stringify(contact),
                remove: JSON.stringify(remove)
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, status, request) {
                status_url = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
                update_progress(status_url, '#progress div');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Unexpected error');
            }
        });
```

I am still getting the data as a string in Python, how can I go about putting this data into some structured format to use? Thanks everyone for your help :)

```
contact%5B%5D=45&contact%5B%5D=200&contact%5B%5D=100&contact%5B%5D=1234&contact%5B%5D=94&contact%5B%5D=123&contact%5B%5D=3490&contact%5B%5D=1234&contact%5B%5D=345&contact%5B%5D=3&contact%5B%5D=4&contact%5B%5D=5&contact%5B%5D=6&contact%5B%5D=7&contact%5B%5D=8&contact%5B%5D=9&contact%5B%5D=10&contact%5B%5D=11&contact%5B%5D=12&remove%5B%5D=3&remove%5B%5D=4&remove%5B%5D=5
```

Comment: won't be json that is sent unless you specify contentType. Look at actual request itself in browser dev tools...will see it is form encoded. See jQuery docs

Comment: Awesome, I'm able to pull in the data to Python now by setting the contentType as in the jQuery docs but I am getting a super long string, any python module/function out there to easily turn this into json data?

Comment: can send as application/json and stringify it yourself JSON.stringify

Comment: I'm sending it via contentType = application/json and then doing JSON.stringify(contact) and in Python I just end up with a super long string, how to decode this in Python?

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({contact: contact, remove: remove})`

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks everyone :)